# Why does my socket connection between two python scripts break if one of them is launched with Popen?

Tags: python, sockets, ipc

So I have two very simple python scripts that communicate over a socket.  Right now they are both running on the same windows PC.

Here's controller.py:

```
import socket
import time
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

HOST = '192.168.1.107'          # The remote host
PORT = 50557                        # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
except:
    Popen([sys.executable, 'driver.py'], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    time.sleep(0.2);
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

s.send(sys.argv[1])
data = s.recv(1024)

s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

And here's driver.py:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                                # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 50557                    # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

while 1:
    print 'Waiting for controller connection.'
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected to ', addr
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print 'Recieved ', data
        if not data: break
        if data == 'Q': quit()
        print 'A.'      
        conn.send(data[::-1])
        print 'B.'
    print 'C.'

conn.close()
```

If I open two `cmd` windows and `python <filename>.py <arg>` them both everything works fine.  I can leave `driver.py` running and run `controller.py` over and over again.  Until I kill the driver by sending a "Q".

The try/except statement opens up a new window and runs `driver.py` if the connection can't be made.  Theoretically this just makes sure that the receiver is running before it sends anything.  This ALMOST works but for some reason `driver.py` hangs inside the second while loop for reasons I cannot explain.  Here's the output from sequential `controller.py` calls:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

>python controller.py FirstMsg
Received 'gsMtsriF'

>python controller.py SecondMsg
Received 'gsMdnoceS'

>python controller.py Q
Received ''

>python controller.py ThirdMsg
Received 'gsMdrihT'

>python controller.py FourthMsg
```

(After FourthMsg `controller.py` hangs forever)

Here's the output from `driver.py`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

>python driver.py
Waiting for controller connection.
Connected to  ('192.168.1.107', 49915)
Recieved  FirstMsg
A.
B.
Recieved
C.
Waiting for controller connection.
Connected to  ('192.168.1.107', 49916)
Recieved  SecondMsg
A.
B.
Recieved
C.
Waiting for controller connection.
Connected to  ('192.168.1.107', 49917)
Recieved  Q
```

(Whereupon it returns to the regular command prompt.)  The new window created with Popen contains this:
    Waiting for controller connection.
    Connected to  ('192.168.1.107', 49918)
    Recieved  ThirdMsg
    A.
    B.

So in the weird new window (which I just noticed does not look or act like a regular cmd window) the program seems to hang on `data = conn.recv(1024)`.

Why does `driver.py` act differently in the new window, and how can I fix it?

Comment: After this line: conn, addr = s.accept()
you don't need a validation to know if the connection is OK, before entering next while?

Answer (score 2):

You asked for sockets and Popen, my answer will ignore this and will try to propose solution for the use case, you have shown - remote communication over network.

With sockets it is very easy to run into never ending problems. If you have both endpoints under your control, zeromq communication will turn your programming back to having fun.

You may either use zeromq directly (if you check examples for `pyzmq`, you will find they are really short and easy while serving very well in many difficult scenarios), but today I will show use of `zerorpc` library, which makes remote calls even simpler.

### Install `zerorpc`

```
$ pip install zerorpc
```

### Write your `worker.py`

```
def reverse(text):
    """ return reversed argument """
    return text[::-1]

def makebig(text):
    """ turn text to uppercase letters """
    return text.upper()
```

### Call worker methods from command line

#### Start server serving worker.py functions

```
$ zerorpc --server --bind tcp://*:5555 worker
binding to "tcp://*:5555"
serving "worker"
```

#### Consume the services (from command line)

Simple call, reporting available functions to call

```
$ zerorpc tcp://localhost:5555
connecting to "tcp://localhost:5555"
makebig turn text to uppercase letters 
reverse return reversed argument
```

Then call these functions:

```
$ zerorpc tcp://localhost:5555 reverse "alfabeta"
connecting to "tcp://localhost:5555"
'atebafla'

$ zerorpc tcp://localhost:5555 makebig "alfabeta"
connecting to "tcp://localhost:5555"
'ALFABETA'
```

Note: so far we have wrote 7 lines of code and are already able calling it remotely.

### Using from Python code

Command line utility `zerorpc` is just handy utility, but you are free to integrate without it, using pure Python.

#### Consuming from python code `client.py`

```
import zerorpc

client = zerorpc.Client()
url = "tcp://localhost:5555"
client.connect(url)

print client.reverse("alfabeta")
print client.makebig("alfabeta")
```

and run it

```
$ python client.py
atebafla
ALFABETA
```

#### Run remote server from python code `server.py`

```
import zerorpc
import worker

url = "tcp://*:5555"

srv = zerorpc.Server(worker)
srv.bind(url)
srv.run()
```

Stop older server started by command `zerorpc`, if it still runs.

Then start out python version of the server:

```
$ python server.py
```

(it does not print anything, just waits to serve).

Finally, consume it from your Python code

```
$ python client.py 
atebafla
ALFABETA
```

### Conclusions

- Using zeromq or zerorpc simplifies the situation a lot
- Play with starting client.py and server.py in various orders
- try to run multiple clients
- try to consume services from another computer (over network)
- zerorpc provides more patterns (streamer, publish/subscribe), see zerorpc test suite
- `zerorpc` solves the integration task and let you focus on coding real functions