# Python application becomes non-responsive due to subprocess

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have written a Python application, using Flask, that serves a simple website that I can use to start playback of streaming video on my Raspberry Pi (microcomputer). Essentially, the application allows be to use my phone or tablet as a remote control.

I tested the application on Mac OS, and it works fine. After deploying it to the Raspberry Pi (with the Raspbian variant of Debian installed), it serves the website just fine, and starting playback also works as expected. But, stopping the playback fails.

Relevant code is hosted here: https://github.com/lcvisser/mlbviewer-remote/blob/master/remote/mlbviewer-remote.py

The subprocess is started like this:

```
cmd = 'python2.7 mlbplay.py v=%s j=%s/%s/%s i=t1' % (team, mm, dd, yy)
player = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=-1, cwd=sys.argv[1])
```

This works fine.

The subprocess is supposed to stop after this:

```
player.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
player.communicate()
```

This *does* work on Mac OS, but it does *not* work on the Raspberry Pi: the application hangs until the subprocess (started as `cmd`) is finished by itself. It seems like `SIGINT` is not sent or not received by the subprocess.

Any ideas?

---

(I have posted this question also here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133946/application-becomes-non-responsive-to-requests-on-raspberry-pi as I don't know if this is an OS problem or if it a Python/Flask-related problem.)

**UPDATE:**
Trying to use `player.communicate()` as suggested by Jan Vlcinsky below (and after finally seeing the warning [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)) did not help.

I'm thinking about using the proposed solution by Jan Vlcinsky, but if Flask does not even receive the request, I don't think that would receive the issue.

**UPDATE 2:**
Yesterday night I was fortunate to have a situation in which I was able to exactly pinpoint the issue. Updated the question with relevant code.

I feel like the solution of Jan Vlcinsky will just move the problem to a different application, which will keep the Flask application responsive, but will let the new application hang.

**UPDATE 3:**
I edited the original part of the question to remove what I now know not to be relevant.

**UPDATE 4:** After the comments of @shavenwarthog, the following information might be very relevant:

On Mac, mlbplay.py starts something like this:

```
rmtpdump <some_options_and_url> | mplayer -
```

When sending `SIGINT` to mlbplay.py, it terminates the *process group* created by this piped command (if I [understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753035/sending-sigint-from-keyboard-to-piped-commands-in-bash) correctly).

On the Raspberry Pi, I'm using omxplayer, but to avoid having to change the code of mlbplay.py (which is not mine), I made a script called mplayer, with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

MLBTV_PIPE=mlbpipe

if [ ! -p $MLBTV_PIPE ]
then
    mkfifo $MLBTV_PIPE
fi

cat <&0 > $MLBTV_PIPE | omxplayer -o hdmi $MLBTV_PIPE
```

I'm now guessing that this last line starts a new process group, which is *not* terminated by the `SIGINT` signal and thus making my app hang. If so, I should somehow get the process group ID of this group to be able to terminate it properly. Can someone confirm this?

**UPDATE 5:** omxplayer does handle `SIGINT`:

https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/blob/master/omxplayer.cpp#L131

**UPDATE 6:** It turns out that somehow my SIGINT transforms into a SIGTERM somewhere along the chain of commands. SIGTERM is not handled properly by omxplayer, which appears to be the problem why things keep hanging. I solved this by implementing a shell script that manages the signals and translates them to proper omxplayer commands (sort-of a lame version of what Jan suggested).

**SOLUTION:** The problem was in `player.send_signal()`. The signal was not properly handled along the chain of commands, which caused the parent app to hang. The solution is to implement  wrappers for commands that don't handle the signals well.

In addition: used `Popen(cmd.split())` rather than using `shell=True`. This works a lot better when sending signals!

Comment: Would you share some code? I would be interested in your Flask code (ideally full working example exhibiting the problem, but at least the part, which does `subprocess.Popen`).

Comment: The full code is hosted here: https://github.com/lcvisser/mlbviewer-remote/blob/master/remote/mlbviewer-remote.py
The subprocess is started on line 142, and stopped on line 163

Answer (score 1):

The problem is marked in following snippet:

```
@app.route('/watch/<year>/<month>/<day>/<home>/<away>/')
def watch(year, month, day, home, away):
    global session
    global watching
    global player

    # Select video stream
    fav = config.get('favorite')
    if fav:
        fav = fav[0] # TODO: handle multiple favorites
        if fav in (home, away):
            # Favorite team is playing
            team = fav
        else:
            # Use stream of home team
            team = home
    else:
        # Use stream of home team
        team = home

    # End session
    session = None

    # Start mlbplay
    mm = '%02i' % int(month)
    dd = '%02i' % int(day)
    yy = str(year)[-2:]
    cmd = 'python2.7 mlbplay.py v=%s j=%s/%s/%s' % (team, mm, dd, yy)
    # problem is here ----->
    player = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, cwd=sys.argv[1])
    # < ------problem is here

    # Render template
    game = {}
    game['away_code'] = away
    game['away_name'] = TEAMCODES[away][1]
    game['home_code'] = home
    game['home_name'] = TEAMCODES[home][1]
    watching = game
    return flask.render_template('watching.html', game=game)
```

You are starting up new process for executing shell command, but do not wait until it completes. You seem to rely on a fact, that the command line process itself is single one, but your frontend is not taking care of it and can easily start another one.

Another problem could be, you do not call `player.communicate()` and your process could block if `stdout` or `stderr` get filled by some output.

## Proposed solution - split process controller from web app

You are trying to create UI for controlling a player. For this purpose, it would be practical splitting your solution into frontend and backend. Backend would serve as player controller and would offer methods like

- start
- stop
- nowPlaying

To integrate front and backend, multiple options are available, one of them being `zerorpc` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944303/346478

Advantage would be, you could very easily create other frontends (like command line one, even remote one).

Comment: I agree that splitting the controller from the interface would be a good idea (even though it seems a bit overkill for this small project). Nonetheless: a) why would the subprocess calling other processes be a problem? (it does, by the way, indeed start a bunch of other processes). b) if it is true that the `std*` buffers get filled up (I guess it is possible that these buffers are smaller on the Raspberry Pi than they are on the Mac), why would it block also the Flask application? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of subprocesses?

Answer (score 0):

One more piece of the puzzle: `proc.terminate()` vs `send_signal`.

The following code forks a 'player' (just a shell with `sleep` in this case), then prints its process information.  It waits a moment, `terminate`s the player, then verifies that the process is no more, it has ceased to be.

Thanks to @Jan Vlcinsky for adding the `proc.communicate()` to the code.

(I'm running Linux Mint LMDE, another Debian variation.)

### source

```
# pylint: disable=E1101

import subprocess, time

def show_procs(pid):
    print 'Process Details:'
    subprocess.call(
        'ps -fl {}'.format(pid),
        shell=True,
    )

cmd = '/bin/sleep 123'
player = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

print '* player started, PID',player.pid
show_procs(player.pid)

time.sleep(3)

print '\n*killing player'
player.terminate()
player.communicate()

show_procs(player.pid)
```

### output

```
* player started, PID 20393
Process Details:
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY        TIME CMD
0 S johnm    20393 20391  0  80   0 -  1110 wait   17:30 pts/4      0:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/sleep 123

*killing player
Process Details:
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY        TIME CMD
```

Comment: I would prefer to send `SIGINT` to the process, as this signal is explicitly handled as a way to gracefully exit the program I'm trying to run. Sending `SIGTERM` seems a bit too rigorous for me.

Comment: @ludo I see your point. Note that `SIGTERM` allows for graceful exit; it's `SIGKILL` that's unmaskable.  I'm looking forward to the solution!

Comment: Unfortunately, mlbplay is a program that is not mine, so I cannot add a `SIGTERM` handler. Moreover, if `SIGINT` does not arrive, why would `SIGTERM`?

Comment: `SIGINT/SIGTERM` should be identical; they're both maskable. What happens if you send SIGTERM, does it act differently than SIGINT?  If you're using the following mlbplay.py, it doesn't have *any* signal handlers.  It's possible the Python proc is getting the signal, but a child proc is not letting it die. http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@m@l@mlbviewer-HEAD@trunk@mlbplay.py

Comment: The link points to an old version; this is the latest: https://sourceforge.net/p/mlbviewer/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mlbplay.py On line 384 it catches KeyboardInterrupt to stop playback. "but a child proc is not letting it die." -> This might be a good point. On Mac OS I'm using a different player than on the Raspberry Pi. Maybe the one on Raspberry Pi doesn't like to be quit via `SIGINT`...!

Comment: I updated the question with more details after the remark about child procs. It seems I'm getting more close to the right solution (so far away from what I thought...)